# ui grid expandable not showing data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, angular-ui-grid, webmethod

I am trying to bind ui-grid in expandable option. I am able to get the data but seems binding wise i am missing something. Can someone advice please

Here is my code

--controller --

```
                            // JavaScript source code
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                expandableRowTemplate: 'expandableRowTemplate.html',
                expandableRowHeight: 150,
                //subGridVariable will be available in subGrid scope
                expandableRowScope: {
                    subGridVariable: 'subGridScopeVariable'
                }
            }

            $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            { name: 'check_number', field: 'check_number', displayName: 'check_number' }

            ];

            var callData = function () {
                alert('call data');
                return $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/Common/Metasystem/AP/Reports/ReportData.aspx/GetcheckReportData",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { beforedt: '01/01/2018', afterdt: '01/01/1900', checknumberlist: '' },
                    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
                }
                )
            };

            $scope.fetchResult =
            function () {
                // alert('call');
                $scope.gridOptions.data = 'aa';
                callData()
                .success(function (resultvalue) {
                    // $scope.resultdata = "[" + JSON.stringify(resultvalue.d) + "]";//issue
                    $scope.resultdata = JSON.parse(resultvalue.d);
                    for (i = 0; i < $scope.resultdata.length; i++) {

                        $scope.resultdata[i].subGridOptions = {
                            columnDefs: [{ name: "check_number", field: "check_number", displayName: 'check_number' }, { name: "voucher_number", field: "voucher_number", displayName: 'voucher_number' }],
                            data: $scope.resultdata[i].friends
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.resultdata;
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    console.error('Repos error', data);
                })
            };
            $scope.fetchResult();
```

--- json data from webmethod

```
            [{
                "Check_number": "116511",
                "Check_date": "2012-11-21T00:00:00",
                "Detail": [{
                    "Check_number": "116511",
                    "Voucher_number": "10000115",
                    "Invoice_number": "10000115",
                    "Invoice_date": "2017-03-23T16:03:38.303",
                    "Invoice_amount": 125.0,
                    "Vendor_number": "01234"    
                }, {
                    "Check_number": "116511",
                    "Voucher_number": "10000115",
                    "Invoice_number": "10000115",
                    "Invoice_date": "2017-03-23T16:03:38.303",
                    "Invoice_amount": 125.0,
                    "Vendor_number": "01234"        
                }]
            }]
```

---------- aspx page

```
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-app="app">
            <div class="control-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="expandAllRows()" value="Expand All"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-small" ng-click="collapseAllRows()" value="Collapse All"/>
            </div>
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-expandable class="grid"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

found it. assignment was wrong.

$scope.gridOptions.data = 'resultdata';